# how to auto-update an app icon in flutter which can change after few hours

Tags: flutter, dart

How to make a live icon in the flutter app? I'm making the weather app in flutter so that the app icon should change after a few hours

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?  From what i understand you want to change a weather icon depending on the hour of the day is that right ?

Comment: Thank you for replying. see just for an example in apple there is a clock icon that shows accurate timing on the app icon only. so I want to build a flutter app in which there should be current weather symbols on an app icon